# Compute the shortest path in a directed acyclic graph

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, discrete-optimization

> **Problem:** Let $D = (V,A)$ be a directed acyclic graph, i.e., there exists no directed cycle in D, and let $w : A → R$ be arc weights. Assume that you are given a topological sort of the vertices. Show how the above ordering can be used to compute single-source shortest paths, with respect to $w$, in $O(m)$ arithmetic operations.
>
> **Solution:** Let $s \in V$ be the vertex that we want to compute the shortest paths from. Consider the vertices in the order of the topological sort, starting from $s$. For each vertex, relax all its outgoing edges. That means if we consider $v ∈ V$ , then for all $(v, u) ∈ A$ set $d ( u ) = \min \{ d ( u ) , d ( v ) + w ( v , u ) \}$. Recall that there are no edges from $v$ to $u$ if $u$ proceeds $v$ in the ordering. Thus, the vertices on any path starting from s obey the ordering. Hence, the sizes of the shortest paths are found by considering each arc at most once.

I am not sure I understood why this function $d$ would give us the "lightest" path from a fixed vertex $s$.

Comment: Use induction to prove that at each stage it has given you the shortest path to the vertices visited. At the beginning $d(w)=0$, which is the shortest distance from $w$ to itself. Assume that the claim is true in some given stage, and prove that it will hold for the next step. You will need to use the property of the topological sort that tells you that all vertices that have incoming edges to the current vertex are vertices in previous stages and therefore you know for them their minimum length of path from $w$.

Comment: I'm looking into that, thank you!